# error in jquery after updating it to 3.3.1

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I recently updated my customized template in my word press theme and suddenly i have this in error.

[image]

and i saw the code that's been causing it.

```
$(document).click(function (event) {
    var clicka;
    clicka = event.target.id;
    if (!$('#' + clicka).parents('.topmenux').length) {
        $('#user_menu_open').removeClass('iosfixed').hide(400);
    }
});
```

I tried changing the # sign to #id or #nameofimage but it's not working. This code is separated to the parent theme file while all of the customized codes are in the child theme. so if i will add the fixed code i need to replace it in the child theme itself. I searched high and low but i can't find any articles that will replace the code in the child theme.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add simple if statement to check if clicka's length is more than 0

like

```
if( clicka.length > 0 ){
    //your code here
}
```

Comment: it says undefined

Comment: ok...$(document).click(function (event) {
    var clicka;
    clicka = event.target.id;
    if( clicka.length > 0 ){
    if (!$('#' + clicka).parents('.topmenux').length) {
        $('#user_menu_open').removeClass('iosfixed').hide(400);
    }
}
});

Comment: sorry @amber. i didn't re read your code. now my problem is how do i replace the javascript file from the child theme.